# Toolbar Not Showing in JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am trying to customize JSQMessagesViewController using container view controller.
I have added header in my parent view controller and in container view i have used JSQMessagesViewController. But the problem is that JSQMessages input toolbar is not showing up using container view.[image]

[image]

toolbar not showing when app is running.

Comment: Junaid, please edit your post with storyboard screen shot and code you have done, so anyone can look into same and help you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion i have edit my post.

Comment: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/94

Comment: Why you are putting JSQMessagesViewController in container view ? is it for navigation bar and tabbar controller management ?

Comment: because i want to add custom view on top of JSQMessagesViewController.It is navigation bar management

Comment: Thanks for your response i had solved by inherit containerviewcontroller with JSQMessagesViewController

Comment: Good Job. have a happy coding.

Post your solution as answer, so that will help to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**
I had solved by inherit ContainerViewController with JSQMessagesViewController
[image]